# How to load HTML document including js.download elements with Python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am trying to collect data from a web page displaying search results about cars on sale.

The structure of the **online** document is not too complex and I was able to single-out the interesting bits of information based on a certain attribute `data-testid` which every returned car record possesses.

[image: data-testid]

I can find different interesting bits of information like price, immatriculation year, mileage and so on, based on substring characteristics of this attribute.

I use `beautifulsoup` to parse the HTML and `requests` to initially load the HTML document from the web.

Now, here's the issue. In a way that I cannot predict, nor find a logic to, the HTML returned by `requests.get()` is somehow *incomplete*. In a page of 100 results, which I can see when I inspect the page **online** (and I can track there are 100 `data-testid` fields with that specific substring for price, 100 for mileage and so on...), the HTML returned by `requests.get()`, in the same way as the one I can obtain with a 'save-as' operation from the page itself, only contains a portion of these fields.

Also their number is kind of unpredictable.

I started asking just [why this discrepancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239795/discrepancy-between-elements-in-the-inspection-pane-of-chrome-and-in-the-source) between online and saved HTML.
So far no full response, but in the comments the hint was that the page was kinda loading dynamically through `JavaScript`.
I was happy to find that saving the page to disk, with all the files, somehow produced the full HTML I could then parse without further issues.

However, my joy only lasted for that specific search. When I needed to try a new one, I was suddenly back to square one.
With further investigation, I came to my current understanding, which is at the origin of the question: I noticed that, when I save the online page as 'Webpage, Complete' (which creates an .html file plus a folder), this combo surely contains ALL records. I can say that because if I go offline and double-click on the newly saved html, I can see all records which were online (100 in this case).
However, the HTML file itself **only** contains a few of them!!!

My deduction is, therefore, that the rest of the records must be 'hidden' in the folder created at saving time, and I would tend to say it could be embedded in those (many) *.js.download files:

[image]

My questions are:

- is my assumption correct? The other records are stored in those files?
- if yes, how can I make them 'explicit' when parsing the HTML with `beautifulsoup`?

**UPDATE 07/05**

I've tried to install and use `requests_html` as suggested in the comments and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603339/how-to-call-javascript-function-using-beautifulsoup-and-python) answer.
Its `render()` method looked promising, however I'm probably not really understanding the mechanisms explained in `requests_html` documentation [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) (the render JS portion) because even after the following operations (pseudo-code)

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(URL)
r.html.render()
```

At this point, I was hoping to have 'forced' the site to 'spit out' ALL HTML, including those bits which remain somehow hidden and only show up in the live page.
However, a successive dump of the `r.html.html` into a file, still gives back the same old 5 records (why 5 now, when for other searches it returned 12, or even 60, is a complete mystery to me).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call JavaScript function using BeautifulSoup and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603339/how-to-call-javascript-function-using-beautifulsoup-and-python)

Comment: I'll be able to tell you once I understand what a 'headless browser' is and how to use it in this context :)
Answer number 4, using `requests-HTML` instead of `request` also gives some hope. Thanks for the pointer!